How to determine the maximum number of batch methods in a single transaction?
How many batch methods can I add in a single transaction? Is there a byte limit, or should I calculate it another way? I get a signature error when I try to send transactions larger than 285 bytes (more than 4 transfer_allow_death method).

Invalid Transaction". Transaction has a bad signature



Do you also get this error when sending other transactions like System::remark? The error sounds unrelated to the batch.

@OliverTale-Yazdi Thanks for your reply. i posted the correct answer

I found the issue: I forgot to hash the payload serialization buffer before signing.
